# export data onto csv and rename after computer profile name

Tags: excel, vba

I want to exportdata from my excel file onto a csv saved in folder S:\froyo\ics. I want to name the csv file after my computer profile name. Im currently using the below code but im not getting the naming part right.

Sub csvfile()

```
Dim fs As Object, a As Object, i As Integer, s As String, t As String, l As String, mn As String
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sUser = Environ("username")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("S:\froyo\ics\sUser.csv", True)
For r = 1 To Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    s = ""
    c = 1
    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(r, c))
        s = s & Cells(r, c) & ","
        c = c + 1
    Wend
    a.writeline s 'write line
Next r
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the s user variable should be concatenated into the string, otherwise, it takes it to be part of the string and not a variable:

```
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("S:\froyo\ics\" & sUser &".csv", True)
```

Comment: also, I'm not sure on this one, but I prefer to reference the value in a cell not the whole object so, use cells(r,c).value rather than cells, but it looks like it should work either way.